# Display/Hide a div on JavaScript hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the image overlay (with text) to only display when the div is hovered over. Hidden by default. By JavaScript if suitable.

I tried duplicating the css, giving the first (display: none) and then the second with :hover and no (display: none), but did not work, so trying with JavaScript to add/remove the (display: none) class.

I've included a live URL. I am reffering to the 6 homepage images.

[image]
[image]

Live URL: http://bit.ly/1jl1QaT

HTML

```
<div class="desc"><p><?=((strlen($r_main['friendlyTitle'])>40)?substr($r_main['friendlyTitle'],0,40).'...':$r_main['friendlyTitle']);?></p></div>
                </div></a>
                <a href="Shopping/"><div class="feature-2">
                    <div class="header"><p>Shopping</p></div>
                    <div class="desc"><p>Grab yourself a pair of Mink Fur Eyelashes for only £19.95 </p></div>
                </div></a>
```

CSS

```
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-1 .desc, #content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-2 .desc, #content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-3 .desc, #content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-4 .desc, #content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-5 .desc, #content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-6 .desc { position:absolute; width: 220px; height: 50px  zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=90); opacity: 0.9; background: #333; bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 5px; display: none; }

#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-1 .desc, #content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-2 .desc, #content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-3 .desc, #content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-4 .desc, #content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-5 .desc, #content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-6 .desc-show { position:absolute; width: 220px; height: 50px     zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=90); opacity: 0.9; background: #333; bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 5px;  }
```

JavaScript

```
$(".desc").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).removeClass("desc-show");
      },
      function () {
        $(this).addClass("desc");
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML

```
<div style="background-color:red;">
<div id="blah">DEMO TEXT ON MOUSE OVER</div>
</div>
```

JAVA-SCRIPT

```
$('#blah').hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(1,1);
},function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(1,0);
});
```

CSS

```
#blah {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/bzaax/276/)

Comment: Please add some code/comments in your answer rather than just linking to a JSFiddle.

Comment: While other answers will probably work if I can implement them correctly (my fault). I've been able to get this one working fine, thanks Ashuthinks. One quick question though too, right now you have to hover specifically over the 30px high div that contains the text, could it be linked to the entire image so you can hover over anywhere on the image and it will show the text? The image is in a seperate div.

Comment: @tokyodrift I have define `width:100px; height:100px;` if you dont give it it will take automatically applied for full div :) enjoy

Comment: The div containing the text has a width and heigh defined, so the texts black bg is always filling the full width (220px) and a height (50px). Therefore I can't not define it.

Comment: @ashuthinks please don't use JavaScript to when you don't need to, see my answer below with a running JSFiddle example

Answer (score 2):

```
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-1{
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    float: left;
    height: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    z-index:-1;
}
#content-mid .col-2 .features .image_holder_home_page{
    height: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
}

#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-1 .header{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0098FF;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 95.5%;
}
```

Please add above css code into your site. because some dive elements are overflowing. this will fix that issue.

Answer (score 0):

try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/FWG8R/). I have used it so many time.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on('mouseenter', '.divbutton', function () {
                    $(this).find(":button").show();
                }).on('mouseleave', '.divbutton', function () {
                    $(this).find(":button").hide();
                });
            });
```

just edit this code and put your div instead of button.

Answer (score 0):

You're CSS is wrong. Please use this tool http://csslisible.com/en/ to get it readable by an human, and you'll see what I mean by "wrong":

```
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-1 .desc,
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-2 .desc,
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-3 .desc,
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-4 .desc,
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-5 .desc,
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-6 .desc {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 220px;
    height: 50px zoom;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    background: #333;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
}

#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-1 .desc, /* #TIP#: this is here */
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-2 .desc, /* #TIP#: this is here */
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-3 .desc, /* #TIP#: this is here */
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-4 .desc, /* #TIP#: this is here */
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-5 .desc, /* #TIP#: this is here */
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-6 .desc-show {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 220px;
    height: 50px zoom;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    background: #333;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
}
```

What about something way easier:

- no JavaScript required,
- less CSS code duplication,

```
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-1 .desc,
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-2 .desc,
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-3 .desc,
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-4 .desc,
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-5 .desc,
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-6 .desc {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 220px;
    height: 50px zoom;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    background: #333;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
}

#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-1:hover .desc,
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-2:hover .desc,
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-3:hover .desc,
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-4:hover .desc,
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-5:hover .desc,
#content-mid .col-2 .features .feature-6:hover .desc {
    display: block;
}
```

**EDIT:** Here's an example on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pomeh/9XX46/

The code:

HTML:

```
<div class="features">

    <a href="Podcasts/">
        <div class="feature feature-1">
            <div class="header"><p>Podcasts</p></div>
            <div class="image_holder_home_page">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/220/159/city" />
            </div>
            <div class="desc"><p>Podcast Simple Page</p></div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="Shopping/">
        <div class="feature feature-2">
            <div class="header"><p>Shopping</p></div>
            <div class="image_holder_home_page">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/220/159/food" />
            </div>
            <div class="desc"><p>Grab yourself a pair of Mink Fur Eyelashes for only £19.95 </p></div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="Confessions/">
        <div class="feature feature-3">
            <div class="header"><p>Confessions</p></div>
            <div class="image_holder_home_page">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/220/159/sports" />
            </div>
            <div class="desc"><p>tttttttttttttttt</p></div>
        </div>
    </a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.features .feature {
    width: 220px;
    height: 50px zoom;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

p {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.features .feature .header {
    width: 100%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
}
.features .feature-1 .header {
    background-color: blue;
}
.features .feature-2 .header {
    background-color: red;
}
.features .feature-3 .header {
    background-color: green;
}

.features .feature .desc {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.9;
    background: #333;
    width: 220px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
}

.features .feature:hover .desc {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Given this a try so I won't have to use the JavaScript too but does not appear to be working. Does not show the div again on hover. Currently got this attempt live on the site.

Comment: Try with replacing the last lines with ".feature-1:hover .desc" instead of ".feature-1 .desc:hover".

Comment: @sebcap26 I've updated my answer and added a JSFiddle demo using no JavaScript, and cleaned up the CSS a bit, you should have a look.